# Filling color in intersected path with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uibezierpath

I am trying to draw a view with few hollow circles in it. The view background color will be black with opacity 0.5 and hollow circles on places where I could see the view underneath it. This is working fine with below piece of code but has an issue when my hollow circles intersects, I want to cover both of them as hollow area but due to even odd rule this is not working out. Any suggestions?
Or any alternatives?

```
- (void)addShadowView {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height) cornerRadius:0];

    for (NSValue *point in self.hollowFrames) {
        UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(point.CGPointValue.x - self.hollowCircleRadius.floatValue, point.CGPointValue.y - self.hollowCircleRadius.floatValue, 2.0 * self.hollowCircleRadius.floatValue, 2.0 * self.hollowCircleRadius.floatValue) cornerRadius:self.hollowCircleRadius.floatValue];

        [path appendPath:circlePath];
    }

    [path setUsesEvenOddFillRule:YES];

    CAShapeLayer *fillLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    fillLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    fillLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    fillLayer.opacity = 0.5;
    [self.layer addSublayer:fillLayer];
}
```

This is how it looks right now. I want the intersected area also to be hollow and not filled with the fillColor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

don't fill the circles, clip out the centers.

Comment: I am not filling the circles but filling the UIBezierPath with even/odd rule. What do u mean by clip out the circle?

Comment: create a cgpath path that matches the inner portion of the circle, add that path to your shape and then you can clip out that portion before filling using the eo rule. that will give you an actual "hollow" circle, vs. a circle with something in the middle. your other option is if you plan on using solid colors for your circles, you can just stroke an ellipse inside a rect and that will give you the same effect.